# Generate plantuml pdfs GitLab CICD

Tags: maven, yaml, cicd, plantuml

I have a maven project. Inside it I have a `_models/` folder where I have some `.puml` files.

I would like to generate the `.png`s from those plantuml files each time I commit.

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - uml

.maven:
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11

test:
  extends: .maven
  script:
    - mvn test

build:
  extends: .maven
  script:
    - mvn package -B

uml:
  image: miy4/plantuml
  script:
    - plantuml -charset UTF-8 ./_models/sequence_diagram.puml
    - plantuml -charset UTF-8 ./_models/class_diagram.puml
    - plantuml -charset UTF-8 ./_models/object_diagram.puml
```

The pipeline passes but the diagrams.png are not created in the _models folder. Do you know why?

In the GitLab pipelines it says: `No diagram found` but when I run locally those commands everything works fine

Thanks :)

Comment: https://plantuml.com/command-line _ You can specify an output directory for all images using the -o switch: _...

Comment: im nor sure where I can add the -o? Also, I just chequed and it says: No diagram found

Comment: try to debug your pipeline. Add `ls .` and `ls ./_models` into first lines of your `script:`